# Countif date prior specific date

Tags: vba, date, count, numbers

I've encountered problem and Im struggling with easy issue.
I want by VBA countif all items prior date.

I am sure that my code + excel file has dates formats, but it doesnt work.
When Im looking for exact date - it works, but when Im adding majority sign - VBA shows me always zero in prompt window.

Do you know where is a problem?

```
Sub test()
Set oWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Dim suma_processed3 As Integer
Dim Rng As Integer


Rng = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If IsDate(Range("AH5")) Then
Call MsgBox("its a date")
Else
Call MsgBox("this is not a date")
End If

suma_processed3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AH2:AH" & Rng), ">" & CDate("26.03.2018"))


Call MsgBox(suma_processed3)

End Sub
```

Comment: Try putting the date in "mm/dd/yyyy" format

Comment: It works. Thank you Scott!

Comment: @ScottCraner please share the answer in the Answer tab, to remove this question from 'unanswered' list. | Alternatively, the question owner (Kris) may do so too.. (: